# this question is regarding React-push-notification when i am trying to install it i am getting few errors

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm-install

So, I am trying to install react-push-notification using npm i react-push-notification into my current project and i am getting a below mention error.

npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\naman.chaturvedi\Desktop\sk\React\node_modules.bin\react-scripts.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

Here i am trying to install react-push-notification